# Spacing for Image between texts

Tags: spacing, asymptote

The image shown below has text and then a lot of spacing in between. How do I minimize the spacing between the image and text?

I do not know if this is useful, but these are the packages I used.

```
 \documentclass[letterpaper,13pt]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[letterpaper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
    \usepackage{asymptote}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{wrapfig} 

 some text inbetween...
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
      \begin{asy}
        size(4cm);
        draw(circle((0,0),1));
        draw((0,0)--(1,0));
        draw((0,0)--(1/2,sqrt(3)/2));
      \end{asy}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\centering\begin{asy}...\end{asy}` instead of `\begin{center}
      \begin{asy} ... \end{asy}
    \end{center}` to reduce the spacing a bit. However, as a float a figure may float anyway.

Comment: If the next page starts with a large unbreakable block, the glue in \parskip or \intextsep may be expanding to fill the page.  See what effect \raggedbottom has.